# How do I check if a string contains another string in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, range, substring

How can I check if a string (`NSString`) contains another smaller string?

I was hoping for something like:

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
NSLog(@"%d",[string containsSubstring:@"hello"]);
```

But the closest I could find was:

```
if ([string rangeOfString:@"hello"] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"sub string doesnt exist");
} 
else {
    NSLog(@"exists");
}
```

Anyway, is that the best way to find if a string contains another string?

Comment: I'd like to see it added as well, but in the meantime it's relatively easy to add it as a category on NSString.

Comment: Using `if ([string rangeOfString:@"hello"] == 0) {...}` there's a type mismatch error for NSRange and int. to fix that, you should change the line to the following:
`if ([string rangeOfString:@"hello"].length == 0) {...}`

Comment: iOS 8 adds containsString: and here is a minimally invasive way to add iOS 7 support http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2014/retrofitting-containsstring-on-ios-7/

Comment: I've been an iOS developer since the beginning and I constantly revisit this post for a quick copy paste. I can't seem to memorize this one. Most visited stackoverflow post in my history.

Answer (score 2490, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```

The key is noticing that `rangeOfString:` returns an `NSRange` struct, and [the documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410144-rangeofstring?language=objc) that it returns the struct `{NSNotFound, 0}` if the "haystack" does not contain the "needle".

---

And if you're on iOS 8 or OS X Yosemite, you can now do: **(*NOTE: This WILL crash your app if this code is called on an iOS7 device).**

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla blah";
if ([string containsString:@"bla"]) {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
}
```

(This is also how it would work in Swift)

Comment: To make a case insensitive search use "if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)"

Comment: @Dave DeLong I was just going to mention a Category that I created for this purpose before I read your edit to the answer!  Since I am primarily a c# developer I am glad that they added a contains method to NSSTring.

Comment: Why does the compiler don't say anything if my deployment target is iOS7 and I use containsString?

Comment: And to further the point made by @Vanja : if you are going to use the [string containsString] shortcut code that was introduced in iOS 8/Yosemite, you can use the following code for a case insensitive string: "[stringToSearch localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:string]", and this one if you want to do a case and diacritic insensitive search: "[stringToSearch localizedStandardContainsString:string]".

Comment: @ScottKohlert Careful, `[stringToSearch localizedStandardContainsString:string]` was introduced in **iOS9**.

Comment: Note that the expression `[string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location != NSNotFound` will be **true** when string is `nil`!

Comment: To keep iOS7 support one can add containsString: dynamically, for iOS8+ this code won't do anything  and genuine containsString: will be used.
`- (void)setupContainsString
{
 SEL containsStringSelector = @selector(containsString:);
 IMP containsStringIMP = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _self, NSString *string) {\
  NSRange range = [_self rangeOfString:string];
  return range.length != 0;
 });

 //The method is added only if class has no implementation of it
 class_addMethod([NSString class],
     containsStringSelector,
     containsStringIMP,
     "c@@:");

}`

Answer (score 168):

For iOS 8.0+ and macOS 10.10+, you can use NSString's native [`containsString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414563-containsstring?language=objc).

For older versions of iOS and macOS, you can create your own (obsolete) category for NSString:

```
@interface NSString ( SubstringSearch )
    - (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)substring;
@end

// - - - - 

@implementation NSString ( SubstringSearch )

- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)substring
{    
    NSRange range = [self rangeOfString : substring];
    BOOL found = ( range.location != NSNotFound );
    return found;
}

@end
```

***Note: Observe Daniel Galasko's comment below regarding naming***

Comment: +1 for clearer resulting code and reusability.  I turned it into the one liner `return [self rangeOfString:substring].location != NSNotFound;` and included it in my refactoring library, es_ios_utils. https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils

Comment: Looks like Apple likes your idea and added this feature in iOS 8 and OSx 10.10 (Yosemite) as @DaveDeLong mentioned in his answer. +1

Comment: The cardinal rule for obj-c categories is to prefix the method name with your 3 letter module prefix. This is the perfect example since it now conflicts with the iOS 7 and 10.10 release

Answer (score 60):

Since this seems to be a high-ranking result in Google, I want to add this:

iOS 8 and OS X 10.10 add the [`containsString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414563-containsstring?language=objc) method to `NSString`. An updated version of Dave DeLong's example for those systems:

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
if ([string containsString:@"bla"]) {
    NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
}
```

Answer (score 41):

```
NSString *myString = @"hello bla bla";
NSRange rangeValue = [myString rangeOfString:@"hello" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (rangeValue.length > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"string contains hello");
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"string does not contain hello!");
}
```

//You can alternatively use following too :

```
if (rangeValue.location == NSNotFound) 
{
    NSLog(@"string does not contain hello");
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"string contains hello!");
}
```

Answer (score 24):

With **iOS 8** and **Swift**, we can use `localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString`  method

```
 let string: NSString = "Café"
 let substring: NSString = "É"

 string.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(substring) // true
```

Comment: This is good. No idea why they didn't have this method for ios 7

Comment: @Lucas, because Swift launched with iOS 8.0. but with swift you can still support the devices with iOS 7.

Answer (score 13):

So personally I really hate `NSNotFound` but understand its necessity.

But some people may not understand the complexities of comparing against NSNotFound

For example, this code:

```
- (BOOL)doesString:(NSString*)string containString:(NSString*)otherString {
    if([string rangeOfString:otherString].location != NSNotFound)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

has its problems:

1) Obviously if `otherString = nil` this code will crash.  a simple test would be:

```
NSLog(@"does string contain string - %@", [self doesString:@"hey" containString:nil] ? @"YES": @"NO");
```

results in  !! CRASH !!

2) What is not so obvious to someone new to objective-c is that the same code will NOT crash when `string = nil`. 
For example, this code:

```
NSLog(@"does string contain string - %@", [self doesString:nil containString:@"hey"] ? @"YES": @"NO");
```

and this code:

```
NSLog(@"does string contain string - %@", [self doesString:nil containString:nil] ? @"YES": @"NO");
```

will both result in

```
does string contains string - YES
```

Which is clearly NOT what you want.

So the better solution that I believe works is to use the fact that rangeOfString returns the length of 0  so then a better more reliable code is this:

```
- (BOOL)doesString:(NSString*)string containString:(NSString*)otherString {
    if(otherString && [string rangeOfString:otherString].length)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

OR SIMPLY:

```
- (BOOL)doesString:(NSString*)string containString:(NSString*)otherString {
    return (otherString && [string rangeOfString:otherString].length);
}
```

which will for cases  1 and 2 will return

```
does string contains string - NO
```

That's my 2 cents ;-)

Please check out my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jlott1/038127cda6e23eaa0942) for more helpful code.

Answer (score 12):

An improved version of [*P i*'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c/6632346#6632346), a category on NSString, that not only will tell, if a string is found within another string, but also takes a range by reference, is:

```
@interface NSString (Contains)
-(BOOL)containsString: (NSString*)substring
              atRange:(NSRange*)range;

-(BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)substring;
@end

@implementation NSString (Contains)

-(BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)substring
              atRange:(NSRange *)range{

    NSRange r = [self rangeOfString : substring];
    BOOL found = ( r.location != NSNotFound );
    if (range != NULL) *range = r;
    return found;
}

-(BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)substring
{
    return [self containsString:substring
                        atRange:NULL];
}

@end
```

Use it like:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello, World!";

//If you only want to ensure a string contains a certain substring
if ([string containsString:@"ello" atRange:NULL]) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}

// Or simply
if ([string containsString:@"ello"]) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}

//If you also want to know substring's range
NSRange range;
if ([string containsString:@"ello" atRange:&range]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRange(range));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Oneliner (Smaller amount of code. DRY, as you have only one `NSLog`):

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
NSLog(@"String %@", ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) ? @"not found" : @"cotains bla");
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a copy-and-paste function snippet:

```
-(BOOL)Contains:(NSString *)StrSearchTerm on:(NSString *)StrText
{
    return [StrText rangeOfString:StrSearchTerm 
        options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound;
}
```

Comment: May I know why I am downvoted ? It's a working code snippet

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *categoryString = @"Holiday Event";
if([categoryString rangeOfString:@"Holiday"].location == NSNotFound)
{
    //categoryString does not contains Holiday
}
else
{
    //categoryString contains Holiday
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try this,

```c
NSString *string = @"test Data";
if ([[string lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"data"].location == NSNotFound) 
{
    NSLog(@"string does not contain Data");
}   
else 
{
    NSLog(@"string contains data!");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Best solution. As simple as this! If you want to find a word or 
part of the string. You can use this code. In this example we are going to check if the value of word contains "acter".

```
NSString *word =@"find a word or character here";
if ([word containsString:@"acter"]){
    NSLog(@"It contains acter");
} else {
     NSLog (@"It does not contain acter");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need this once write:

```
NSString *stringToSearchThrough = @"-rangeOfString method finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the receiver.";
BOOL contains = [stringToSearchThrough rangeOfString:@"occurence of a given string"].location != NSNotFound;
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 4:

```
let a = "Hello, how are you?"
a.contains("Hello")   //will return true
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of swift, this can be used

```
let string = "Package #23"
if string.containsString("Package #") {
    //String contains substring
}
else {
    //String does not contain substring
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If do not bother about case-sensitive string.
 Try this once.

```
NSString *string  = @"Hello World!";

if([string rangeOfString:@"hello" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location !=NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"found");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 And Above**

```
let str = "Hello iam midhun"

if str.contains("iam") {
  //contains substring
}
else {
  //doesn't contain substring
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *stringData = @"Hello iam midhun";

if ([stringData containsString:@"iam"]) {
    //contains substring
}
else {
    //doesn't contain substring
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Swift 4.1 , 4.2:**

```
let stringData = "Black board"

//swift quick way and case sensitive
if stringData.contains("bla") {
    print("data contains string");
}

//case sensitive
if stringData.range(of: "bla",options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
    print("data contains string");
}else {
    print("data does not contains string");
}
```

**For Objective-C:**

```
NSString *stringData = @"Black board";

//Quick way and case sensitive
if ([stringData containsString:@"bla"]) {
    NSLog(@"data contains string");
}

//Case Insensitive
if ([stringData rangeOfString:@"bla" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
   NSLog(@"data contains string");
}else {
   NSLog(@"data does not contain string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code

```c
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) 
{
    NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} 
else 
{  
    NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the option NSCaseInsensitiveSearch with rangeOfString:options:

```
NSString *me = @"toBe" ;
NSString *target = @"abcdetobe" ;
NSRange range = [target  rangeOfString: me options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
NSLog(@"found: %@", (range.location != NSNotFound) ? @"Yes" : @"No");
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
// your code
}
```

Output result is found:Yes

The options can be "or'ed" together and include:

NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
NSLiteralSearch
NSBackwardsSearch and more

Answer (score -1):

First string contain or not second string,

```
NSString *first = @"Banana";
NSString *second = @"BananaMilk";
NSRange range = [first rangeOfString:second options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (range.length > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Detected");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Not detected");
}
```