# iPhone Objective-C: If string contains...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

How can I tell if a string contains something? Something like:

```
if([someTextField.text containsString:@"hello"]) {

}
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong to minus here:)

Comment: Same as [
String contains string in objective-c (iphone)
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/string-contains-string-in-objective-c-iphone).

Answer (score 22):

You could use:

```
if ( result && [result rangeOfString:@"hello"].location != NSNotFound ) {
    // Substring found...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString`

```
NSRange range = [myStr rangeOfString:@"hello"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
  NSLog (@"Substring found at: %d", range.location);
}
```

View more here: [NSString rangeOfString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:)

Comment: In what Universe is that answer "a little bit tricky"?

Comment: Because for me, from the background of java. We should use [str contains:], so when I discovered the API, it looks a little bit strange. I think the questioner think the same so I say a little bit tricky

Comment: hahahaha Jeremy's post just made me lol

Answer (score 2):

If the intent of your code is to check if a string contains another string you can create a category to make this intent clear.

```
@interface NSString (additions)

- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)subString;

@end

@implementation NSString (additions)

- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)subString {
    BOOL containsString = NO;

    NSRange range = [self rangeOfString:subString];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        containsString = YES;
    }

    return containsString;
}

@end
```

I have not compiled this code, so maybe you should have to change it a bit.

Quentin