# objective c: if something has something in it - do something

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, while-loop

I want to do this:

```
while(theString (does not have) @"this string" (in it)) {
do something
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/string-contains-string-in-objective-c-iphone) stackoverflow post:

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```

> The key is noticing that
>   rangeOfString: returns an NSRange
>   struct, and the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfString_) says
>   that it returns the struct
>   `{NSNotFound, 0}` if the "haystack" does
>   not contain the "needle".

Comment: Thank you for the +1, but do please note that my post is a quote of another answer to an identical question - the original poster really deserves it more than me!