# iPhone : How to check whether a substring exists in a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have some string name and I want to compare whether that string contains substring like "_thumb.png".

Comment: Please check the more complete answer to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/string-contains-string-in-objective-c

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
[string rangeOfString:string1].location!=NSNotFound
```

[rangeOfString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:) documentation.

Answer (score 16):

You can try this:

```
NSString *originalString;
NSString *compareString;
```

Let your `string` be stored in `originalString` and the `substring` that you want to compare is stored in `compareString`.

```
if ([originalString rangeOfString:compareString].location==NSNotFound)
{       
    NSLog(@"Substring Not Found");  
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Substring Found Successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ssteinberg's answer looks pretty good, but there is also this:

```
NSRange textRange;
textRange =[string rangeOfString:substring];

if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)
{

//Does contain the substring
}
```

which I found [here](http://objcolumnist.com/2009/04/12/does-a-nsstring-contain-a-substring/).

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
}  
else 
{
    NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ios 8` or OS `X 10.10` we can use.

```
if(![textLine containsString:@"abc"])
{
     [usableLines addObject:textLine];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can go through this

http://objcolumnist.com/2009/04/12/does-a-nsstring-contain-a-substring/