# NSString search whole text for another string

Tags: iphone, nsstring, compare

I would like to search for an NSString in another NSString, such that the result is found even if the second one does not start with the first one, for example:

eg: I have a search string "st". I look in the following records to see if any of the below contains this search string, all of them should return a good result, because all of them have "st".

Restaurant

stable

Kirsten

At the moment I am doing the following:

```
NSComparisonResult result = [selectedString compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
```

This works only for "stable" in the above example, because it starts with "st" and fails for the other 2. How can I modify this search so that it returns ok for all the 3?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not google first?

[String contains string in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/string-contains-string-in-objective-c)

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I did try googling, but somehow did not get the correct search term and it was not coming up with valid answers..also searched documentation, but yes I accept that I should have tried harder.

Answer (score 1):

Compare is used for testing less than/equal/greater than. You should instead use `-rangeOfString:` or one of its sibling methods like `-rangeOfString:options:range:locale:`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread thought it might help someone.

The `- rangeOfString:options:range:` method will allow for case insensitive searches on a string and replace letters like ‘ö’ to ‘o’ in your search.

```
NSString *string = @"Hello Bla Bla";
NSString *searchText = @"bla";
NSUInteger searchOptions = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch;
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
NSRange foundRange = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:searchOptions range:searchRange];
if (foundRange.length > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Text Found.");
}
```

For more comparison options [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Search_and_Comparison_Options)

Documentation on the method `- rangeOfString:options:range:` can be found on the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:options:range:)