# Find one string in another with case insensitive in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, substring, nsstring

My question is similar to [How do I check if a string contains another string in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2753956/602011)

How can I check if a string (NSString) contains another smaller string but with ignoring case?

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
```

I was hoping for something like:

```
NSLog(@"%d",[string containsSubstring:@"BLA"]);
```

Anyway is there any way to find if a string contains another string with ignore case ? But please do not convert both strings to UpperCase or to LowerCase.

Comment: i am sorry but it is confusing me..!!

Comment: Why don't you want to do it by converting both strings to lowercase / uppercase? That would be the best way to do it or use `NSRegularExpression`.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As similar to the answer provided in the link, but use `options`.

See `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask` in [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416849-rangeofstring?language=objc)

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";

if ([string rangeOfString:@"BLA" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```

Answer (score 17):

From iOS 8 you can add the `containsString:` or  `localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString`  method to NSString.

```
if ([string localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:@"BlA"]) {
    NSLog(@"string contains Case Insensitive bla!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *string = @"hello BLA";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
[string rangeOfString:@"bla" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-(NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask;` to get a range for a substring, the `mask` parameter is used to specify case insensitive match.

Example :

```
NSRange r = [str rangeOfString:@"BLA"
                       options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3aoptions%3a), the method returns a range like `{NSNotFound, 0}` when the substring isn't found.

```
BOOL b = r.location == NSNotFound;
```

**Important** this method raises an exception if the string is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4:

```swift
extension String {
    func containsCaseInsensitive(string : String) -> Bool {
        return self.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(string)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
print("Hello".containsCaseInsensitive(string: "LLO"))
```

Output:

```
true
```