# NSString containString - without whitespace

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm trying to check if an `NSString` contains a substring. It's not working however as there is no space between the words in the string. e.g. I need to find out if 'hello' exists in this string:

@"test.hello"

`NSString containsString` does not find it. Any other solutions?

Comment: Unless Apple has done something weird with that interface `[@"test.hello" containsString:@"hello"]` should return `YES`.

Comment: @HotLicks I thought so but it wasn't working for me. I've accepted the working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 8 has a new method, localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString: also, in addition to containsString:.

```
NSString *testString = @"test.hello";
BOOL found = [testString localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:@"Hello"];
NSLog(@"%@", found ? @"Yes":@"No"); // prints Yes
```

Comment: Good to know thanks! That was only part of the problem though. I had to separate the string into components as the containsString methods search for parts of a string, they won't pick out a string within a string (e.g. they can't get 'boo' from 'aaabooaaa').

Comment: @kmcgrady, this method will return YES for the example you gave (finding boo in 'aaabooaaa'). Are you saying that it won't do that?

Comment: Apologies, didn't think it would work but I just tested it and it does. Much more compact than my solution too. Thanks!

Comment: @kmcgrady, do you see either of theses methods in your Xcode documentation? I only found them with a search on SO.

Comment: @rdelmar - They are not in the online documentation, and, worse, if you search for them you're apt to find some 3rd-party categories by the same name.

Comment: The only reliable place I can find it is NSHipster: http://nshipster.com/ios8/ I can't see it in any documentation.

Comment: I found them in a "New for iOS 8" presentation from Apple, but no actual documentation.

Comment: @HotLicks, I did find them in the NSString.h file where there is a comment explaining their use.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This works but @rdelmar's answer is much more compact.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I discovered an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258606/iphone-find-one-string-in-another-with-case-insensetive) elsewhere on SO. Basically I had to use NSRange and check via the following method:

```
[string rangeOfString:@"hello" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
```

I also had to split my string before doing the check. So in the example words are separated by a period. I called:

```
NSArray *myArray = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."]];
```

and the looped through that array of strings doing the `rangeOfString` search. I set a BOOL so that once my string 'hello' was found it stopped searching.