# How to check whether a specific substring exists in a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I know that I can use the statement: `[string1 rangeOfString:compareString].location!=NSNotFound` to check if a string contains a substring. However, I was wondering how specific this comparison was. If I am checking for the string "birthday" and the string was actually "birthdayy", would it still come up as True?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String contains string in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/string-contains-string-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rangeOfString:` methods look for substrings within a string. The string "birthday" is a substring of "birthdayy", so your expression will return `YES`.

If you want to match whole words only, you need to look at word boundaries: break up the string into an array with `componentsSeparatedByString:` and test each element, or use a regular expression.