# How to create a method to return an array with object of another class?

Tags: objective-c

I have a class of `AddressCards.h/m`, and another class of `AddressBook`,now I want to create a search method to look for names in the AddressBook class but getting some error.

I think I need my method to return an AddressCards type pointer but I'm not sure how to return it, since I need to have an array holding the names in case there is more than 1 match..

This is my current code:

```
  -(NSMutableArray *) searchName:(NSString *) someName{

        NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray alloc];

        for (NSString *name in book)
        {
            if ([someName caseInsensitiveCompare:name] == NSOrderedSame)
                [results addObject:name];
        }
        return results;
    }

@end
```

I'm getting error in this line: `if ([someName caseInsensitiveCompare:name] == NSOrderedSame)`
That says `signal 1 SIGABRT` which I have no idea what is it :/

this is the method that adds addresscards:

```
-(void) addCard:(AddressCards *)theCard{

    [book addObject:theCard];
}
```

Comment: How is book being initialized?  Also SIGABRT just means an abort signal has been thrown.  You should set a break point and inspect for more information

Comment: @JasonSperske thanks. this is book '@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *book;'

Comment: @JasonSperske and i added to the question the method that adds addresscards

Comment: I would recommend being careful using `caseInsensitiveCompare:`. `NSOrderedSame` is defined as 0. If `someName` is `nil` (which evaluates to 0 also), you can get a false positive. I would rewrite your condition to `if ( someName != nil && [someName caseInsensitiveCompare:name] == NSOrderedSame )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`book` is an NSMutableArray of `AddressCards`, however you are trying to iterate over the objects using an NSString (`name`).

You should iterate using `addressCards` object and then make the comparison using the corresponding `name` property. I believe you should implement the searching method similar to the code below:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) searchName:(NSString *) someName{

    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (AddressCards *addressCard in book)
    {
        // do your comparison check here
        // assuming that you have a name property in AddressCards class

        if ([addressCard.name rangeOfString:someName].location != NSNotFound)
            [results addObject:addressCard.name];
    }
    return results;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: Modified the comparison code as desired using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2754075/1576979).

Comment: I was just writing this same answer, but I refreshed and saw you already wrote it :)

Comment: @tolgamorf thanks man :) how would you test it in the main? after calling [someAddressBook searchNam:@"some name"];

Comment: @tolgamorf something else I would like to ask if you dont mind, is why if im writing just part of the name like "john" instead of "john bigs" it wont work..isn't it suppose to?

Comment: just add an NSLog before returning the results. NSLog(@"results array: %@", results);

Comment: @JohnBigs it is due to the comparison method you are using. You should check if someName is a substring of addressCard.name

Comment: @JohnBigs You can find how to do it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2754075/1576979).

Comment: @JohnBigs you're welcome, I updated the code replacing the comparison method.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that you haven't called `init` when creating your `results` array.

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray alloc];
```

should be:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

This will definitely cause a `SIGABRT` error.