# What's wrong with this Objective-C regex?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm trying to detect any words between asterisks:

```
NSString *questionString = @"hello *world*";
NSMutableAttributedString *goodText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:questionString]; //should turn the word "world" blue

    NSRange range = [questionString rangeOfString:@"\\b\\*(.+?)\\*\\b" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        DLog(@"found a word within asterisks - this never happens");
        [goodText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:range];
    }
```

But I never get a positive result. What's wrong with the regex?

Comment: what is questionString?

Comment: There is no word boundary there.  Try adding a search for zero or more whitespace characters.

Comment: check this link it's helps to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/string-contains-string-in-objective-c

Comment: Nevermind about the whitespace, but still there is no word boundary as far as I can tell.

Comment: @manujmv I edited the question to show questionString.

Comment: @borrrden how would I change the regex to include a word boundary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@"\\B\\*([^*]+)\\*\\B"
```

should achieve what you expect.

You have to use `\B` in place of `\b` for word boundaries, as per [Difference between \b and \B in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex).

Finally, using `[^*]+` matches each pair of asterisks, instead of the outermost only.

For instance, in the string

> Hello *world* how *are* you

it will correctly match `world` and `are`, instead of `world how are`.

Another way for achieving the same is using `?` which will make the `+` non-greedy.

```
@"\\B\\*(.+?)\\*\\B"
```

---

Also it's worth noting that `rangeOfString:options` returns the range of the first match, whereas if you are interested in all the matches you have to use build a `NSRegularExpression` instance with that pattern and use its `matchesInString:options:range:` method.

Comment: This works. But if the string is "hello \*world\* how \*are\* you", "how" also turns blue.

Comment: No it doesn't. The rest of your code does, since you are using `rangeOfString` which will return the range of the first match.

Comment: If you want to retrieve all the matches, you have to use the ` matchesInString:options:range:` method of `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I can remove the asterisks after I do the regex test? I just want to turn the word blue. The asterisks shouldn't be displayed. I can't do stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString on goodText because it is an NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to break down the string in `NSString` instances, remove the asterisks, and compose the attributed string again.

Comment: P.S. in this case `?` doesn't mean "optional", it means "non-greedy" right?