# compare last 6 or 8 character of nsstring into some other nsstring

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, string-comparison

I have a string *strSearchNumber = @"9970405060" and want to check whether it is present in string *strPhoneMobile = @"+91997040560"

How can I check if last 6 or 8  characters of my string are present in some other string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code you have tried and need help with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `-[NSString hasSuffix:]`.

Comment: Thanks i tried that code after i posted the question. Anyways thanks alot for help.

Comment: @Mak13 this code will not help you in any string search. But only checks the end part for the search string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NSString` method `hasSuffix:`

```
NSString *strSearchNumber = @"9970405060";
NSString *strPhoneMobile  = @"+91997040560";
if ([strPhoneMobile hasSuffix: strSearchNumber]) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[How do I check if a string contains another string in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/string-contains-string-in-objective-c)

Better then just checking the end or front of the string. You should check if the string contains the other bit of string. The link above will give you the answer.

Underneath the short version of the answer.

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```