# Finding substring in string with input string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, substring

If string is "Testing for Group" then how to find if "rou" is substring.

By using method on this link

[substring with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c)

only gives **complete word** like substring is present or not.

like "for" in above string , but I want to find "or" , "rou" like strings present in string or not.

How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

my code

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    int count=0;
    arrayGroupName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if ([searchText isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        arrayGroupName=permArrayGroupName;
    }
    else
    {
        while (count!=[permArrayGroupName count])
        {


            if ([[[[permArrayGroupName objectAtIndex:count] objectGroupName]capitalizedString] rangeOfString:[searchText capitalizedString]].location == NSNotFound )
            {
                NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"found");
                [arrayGroupName addObject:[permArrayGroupName objectAtIndex:count]];
            }
            /*if ([[[[permArrayGroupName objectAtIndex:count] objectGroupName]capitalizedString] hasPrefix:[searchText capitalizedString]])
            {
                [arrayGroupName addObject:[permArrayGroupName objectAtIndex:count]];
            }*/
            count++;
        }
    }
    [tableGroupList reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Please show you actual code. `rangeOfString:` does NOT only match complete words.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch my code

Comment: Looks okay to me. You should inspect which string are actually compared, maybe your inputs are not what you expect. Try to replace your "not found" NSLog with this `NSLog(@"string \"%@\" does not contain \"%@\"", [[[permArrayGroupName objectAtIndex:count] objectGroupName]capitalizedString], [searchText capitalizedString]);` to see which strings are actually used.

Comment: Thanks I got answer, in my code I just removed capitalizedString, now its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
NSString *string=@"Testing for Group";

if ([string rangeOfString:@"rou"].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Not found");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Found");
}
```