# How to check string contains characters?

Tags: ios, nsstring, range, string-comparison

How to check a string contains a particular character or word.
In my case I have a string "**red manual**". Here I have to check for **"red ma"** in my string.
I tried it by using range of string methods but its not satisfying the condition.

Here is my code

```
 NSString *string = @"red manual";
 NSRange newlineRange = [string rangeOfString:@"red ma"];
 if(newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) 
 {
     NSLog(@"found");
 }
 else
 {
     NSLog(@"not found");
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c

Comment: You can use regex if rangeOfString don't work ;)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please note just because you are using the `xcode IDE` doesn't mean you should be using the `xcode` tag. The `xcode` tag is reserved for issues relating to the `xcode IDE` itself not issues you are having writing code in the `xcode IDE`. When asking a question if you think you need to use the `xcode` tag more than likely you shouldn't be using it at all.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```

The key is noticing that `rangeOfString`: returns an `NSRange struct`, and the documentation says that it `returns` the `struct {NSNotFound, 0}` if the "haystack" does not contain the "needle".

> And if you're on iOS 8 or OS X Yosemite, you can now do:

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla blah";
if ([string containsString:@"bla"]) {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
}
```

it is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c/2754075#2754075) here

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
 NSString *data = @"red manual";

 if ([data rangeOfString:@"red ma" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"not matched");
 }
 else {
    NSLog(@"matched");
}
```

Comment: Which way is the check happening? Is it checking if @"red ma" contains any of the characters from data or, is it checking if data has any of the characters from @"red ma"?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: this will check if data has @"red ma" string in it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [great NSHipster page about NSRange](http://nshipster.com/nsrange/), it should explain things a bit better than Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = @"red manual";
if([string rangeOfString:@"red ma"].location == NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"found");
}
```