# Finding a Char in UILabel - XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, char, uilabel

I'm trying to find characters (e.g. A,b,c) within a UILabel, 
I'm using random words from a .plist file for the words but would like to hide the buttons not containing the letters of the selected word.

Is it possible in Objective-C

Thank You in advance

Comment: You can achieve what you desire, by studying the answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c), and a little more. Please search exhaustively before posting a new questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([UILabel.text rangeOfString:@"a"].location != NSNotFound)
{
   // do stuff here
}
```

UILabe.text is a NSString, so just search on how to do what you are asking for a NSString.