# How to filter sentence by containing words in UISearchbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I have an array of objects.
Object body is a sentence, and i want to filter my `UITableView` by the word of this sentence.

For example, I have to objects:

Id: 1;
Body: "Hello my dear friend";

Id: 2;
Body: "Frodo, give me the ring!";

And if i begin to enter "Fr" `UISearchControler` must return both of objects, because both contains the words begins with "Fr" ("frodo, friend"). Then if I enter "Fro" it will return second object.

Now I'm splitting the messages into array of words, and filterring them with

```
@"self.body contains[c]%@", searchString
```

predicate.

How can i combine contains and beginwith predicates?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c May be this can be helpful , You might want to use `NSRange` for this purpose.

Comment: This post helps to know - does the string contains? But how to filter my arrayOfObject to filterredArrray? I think I heve to use predicates, but I don't know how to configure it for my purpose )

Comment: Yes With `NSRange` way you will have to manually do a loop .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write this code in **SearchBar Delegate** method

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText   
{ 
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains%@",searchTxt.uppercaseString];
   NSArray* FilteredArr = [objTableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

}
```

also take care about cases(lowercase and uppercase )

Comment: it was so easy.. just needt to use contains )) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Code example below:

```
 NSArray* words =  [body componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

 NSArray* seacrhedWords = [words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[c] %@", seacrhText]];
```