# How to fill in a query with variable terms for user and password

Tags: objective-c, http

I need to fill in a query with a username and password. An example is 
 this: 
cgi-bin/videostream.cgi?user=&pwd=

However, these queries are not standardised so in another example, the keys could actually look like cgi-bin/videostream.cgi?passwd=&usr= .

Is there a clean solution that allows me to fill in these queries without using countless if/else statements? It is not possible to standardise the queries.

Comment: how you want to fill? from text field? from string?

Comment: I probably wasn't clear in my explanation. With user=%@&pwd=%@, the issue isn't filling, but rather recognising when it's asking for user or password, because the keys can variate between a lot of options like user=&pwd=, usr=&pw=, userAccount=&userPassword= and sometimes they swap the keys around, making password the first key like this: passwd=&usr=. My question is whether it's possible to have a clean method that is able to figure out when the key is a password and when it's a user key. An example I thought of was checking for a u or p after the question mark, but this isn't very clean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c You could use that check for `&u`, `&p`, `?u`, `?p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on `?`, then split on `&`.

The first string will be something like `cgi-bin/videostream.cgi`, the second like `user=&pwd=` or `passwd=&usr=`. Then, if you split on `&` you will get `user=` and `pwd=`, or `passwd=` and `usr=`. You can then freely append the parameters and concatenate the string.