# Program for string pattern using nested for-loop

Tags: objective-c, command-line

I need a program to print string like as follow below in the objective c:

```
PARTHIBAN
 ARTHIBA
  RTHIB
   THI
    H
```

I have tried with (*)

Code:

```
int i,j,k,height;
NSString *name;
NSLog(@"Enter the name: %@",name);
NSLog(@"Enter the height:");
scanf("%i",&height);
for (i=height;i>=1;i--)
{
    for(k=height-1;k>=i;k--)
    {
        NSLog(@" ");
    }
    for (j=i; j>=1; j--)
    {
        NSLog(@"*");
    }
}
```

Can you please help me print the string as mentioned above in Objective-C?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains another string in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *name = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"PARTHIBAN"];
while (name.length > 1) {
    [name deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    [name deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(name.length - 1, 1)];
    NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
}
```

**EDIT:** I noticed you want to print a string with format, try this:

```
NSMutableString *name = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"PARTHIBAN"];
for (int i = 0; i < name.length / 2; i++ ) {
    [name replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1) withString:@" "];
    [name replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(name.length - 1 - i, 1) withString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for Reply, But I need a program with nested for loop. Can you please make it and share? To print a like 

PARTHIBAN
 ARTHIBA
  RTHIB
     THI
       H

Comment: @Parthiban why nested loop?

Comment: Its my requirement. Look my question as i tried to print (*) i need to print.that's why.