# IOS how to check the value of an array if it contains a certain value and display it out

Tags: ios, arrays, loops, for-loop

I hava an array feed which contains a set of values when i log it out in the console. which looks like this in my log.

Final Feed : (
        {
        hello = red;
    },
        {
        hello = green;
    },
        {
        hello = blue;
    },
        {
        hello = blue;
    },
        {
        hello = blue;
    }

However, when i use a for loop to loop the index to retrieve the values of "blue" and do a counting on how many "blue" it fails.

here is my codes

```
 - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

        NSLog(@"Final Feed : %@",feeds);

        int count = 0;
        int i;
        NSString *value;
        for (i = 0; i < [feeds count]; i++) {
            NSString *bookTitle = [feeds objectAtIndex:i];


            if([[feeds objectAtIndex:i]  isEqual: @"{hello = blue;}"]){


             count++;


            }
                        }
NSLog(@"Total Warning count is:  %d",count);
    }
```

The question now is how do i loop the array name feeds which contains the value "blue" and do a count?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c

Comment: yes it say arc implicit does not allow rangeOfString

Comment: try like `[[[feeds objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"hello"] isEqualToString:@"blue"]`

Comment: You have an array of dictionaries, not an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `feeds` is array of dictionary so try following code:

```
NSInteger count = 0;
for (NSDictionary *feed in feeds) {
    if ([feed[@"hello"] isEqualToString:@"blue"]) {
        count++;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)count);
```

Comment: Thank You. you are right. my feed array is a dictionary.