# What iOS rangeofString do when main string is nil and substring is not nil?

Tags: ios, nsstring

```
NSString *result = nil;
if([result rangeOfString:@"SUCCESS"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"Location: %lu", [result rangeOfString:@"SUCCESS"].location);
    NSLog(@"Length: %lu", [result rangeOfString:@"SUCCESS"].length);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"NULL found:  %@", result);
}
```

this code shows output:

```
2016-05-12 18:51:44.589 TestProject[21666:207505] Location: 0

2016-05-12 18:51:44.590 TestProject[21666:207505] Length: 0
```

Actually It should show output:

```
NULL found:  (null)
```

Please explain the reason of that output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the below link i got good explanation regarding this type of issue :

[How do I check if a string contains another string in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c)

Specially you can read @ucangetit's answer.

You can follow this two function ....

```
- (BOOL)doesString:(NSString*)string containString:(NSString*)otherString {
    if(otherString && [string rangeOfString:otherString].length)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

OR SIMPLY:

```
- (BOOL)doesString:(NSString*)string containString:(NSString*)otherString {
    return (otherString && [string rangeOfString:otherString].length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if `range.length == 0` => is not found.

```
NSString *result = nil;
NSRange range = [result rangeOfString:@"SUCCESS"];//location=0, length=0
if(range.length > 0) //Found
{
    NSLog(@"Location: %lu", range.location);
    NSLog(@"Length: %lu", range.length);
}
```