# Extracting string based object from array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have any `NSarray` of `NSString` objects.

I want to extract those string which only contains character or character&numeric from it.

For example: "D6,Bombay.Hello”" is valid whereas “123456.123,56” is invalid.

Please help if anyone have idea.

Comment: can you share the array please?

Comment: @AntonyRaphel-here is an array (
1.1,
Detais of members,
holder,
more than 5% of total,
d up capital,
Name of the Share Holders,
Mr John,
ABC Limited,
No. of Share,
2,34,105 74.50,
14,440 04.60,
28.940,
09.21,
2013-14,
234,105 74.50,
14,440 04.60,
28940 09.21,
)

Comment: Possbile duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter array using predicate to get only

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id str, NSDictionary *unused) {
    return ([str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound);
}];

NSArray *filtered = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(your_str containsString:xxx){
   // do sth
}
```