# How to Find a Substring in the String in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to find a word  in a string i.e,whether a word is present in particular string or not.

**String 1 Has:**

Case Number
1
 SKU Barcode

---

**String 2 Has:**

Case Number

I want to find whether Case Number is present in string 1 or not .

```
if ([string1 rangeOfString:string2].location !=NSNotFound) {

        NSLog(@"matched");} 
else 
{ NSLog(@"not matched");}
```

but here i am getting not matched ...why ..And then what is the difference of using .location and .length
Output:

2017-05-04 11:38:33.128495 Link[26540:17390387] String 1: Case Number
1
 SKU Barcode

---

2017-05-04 11:38:33.129301 Link[26540:17390387] String 2: Case Number

Thanks in  advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains another string in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c)

Comment: @RajeshkumarR, I am using same only but why i am getting not matched result ..i am asking that only .Please help me

Comment: Can you NSLog string1 and string2 and paste here?

Comment: post ur strings data in ur question @ChandrikaVisvesh

Comment: Could you log `[string1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and the same for `string2`? There may be a invisible space between them or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string1 = @"Case Number \n 1 \n SKU Barcode";
NSString *string2 = @"Case Number";
if ([string1 rangeOfString:string2].location !=NSNotFound) {

    NSLog(@"matched");}
else
{ NSLog(@"not matched");}

}
```

It works for me.

Comment: ,String one 1 has three lines ,case number is in 1st line ,1 in 2nd line , SKU Barcode in 3 rd line

Comment: Can you show how you've created string1 and string2?

Comment: It is coming from server , i have not created this string

Comment: @ChandrikaVisvesh Can you NSLog string1 and string2 and paste here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143352/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-chandrika-visvesh).

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting iOS 8.0 onwards, you can use `containsString`:

```
if ([string1 containsString:string2])
    NSLog(@"matched");
else
    NSLog(@"not matched");
```

If this doesn't work, then there's something wrong with one or both of your strings (e.g. additional space or control characters at the end).

Answer (score 0):

Your string2 contains characters other than @"Case Number".  Test by inserting the following lines into your code.

```
if([string2 isEqualToString:@"Case Number"]) NSLog(@"String 2 is OK");
else NSLog(@"String 2 is bad!");
```