# IOS : containsObject Check for String

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have Array of String like:
Array = P123, P234, P543, P678

and i have string like P12300.(this can be same string inside array or without trailling zeros).

i was using containsObject

```
if(Array containsObject: P123)    ==> TRUE
if(Array containsObject: P23400)  ==> FALSE
if(Array containsObject: P1230)    ==> FALSE
```

is there any better way to compare string so that above ALL case's will be true?

at present i am using containsObject, and i am not getting desired result as condition will be only true for exact same string.

Please let me know good way..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Objective c**

You can use `NSPredicate` for that.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[c] %@", @"P123"];
NSArray *filterArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
if (filterArray.count > 0) {
    print("Contains")
}
else {
    print("Not")
}
```

**Swift**

**Yes**, You can check like that, you need to simply use `contains(where:)` for that.

```
if yourArray.contains(where: { $0.hasPrefix("P123") }) {
    print("Contains")
}
else {
    print("Not")
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to ignore the trailing zeros you can truncate the trailing  zero before comparing it with array.

```
NSString *str = @"P12300";
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"0*$" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", str); //P123
//Now use this str to check its inside the array or not
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[c] %@", str];
```

Comment: yourArray.contains there is no contains property ?

Comment: @user2813740 This is Swift, I haven't check question is tagged with Objective C let me edit my answer.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra, this is the best part of StackOverflow and we all developers. Keep adding good answers to help the community.

Comment: @Hemang Yes, Thats why I up voted his ans immediately. And it is fun too. :)

Comment: @AbhishekMitra, I too. ;)

Comment: what if i have array = P123,P234 and i have to check for P12300

Comment: @user2813740 You mean you want to compare it by ignoring the suffix `0's` ?

Comment: yes .... as Array comping from DB i do not have Control over it.... String is by scanning so i need to check if (array P123 , P234) is having P12300. ignore zero.

Comment: @user2813740 Check the edited answer, also I have changed in predicate with `BEGINSWITH` instead of `contains` make it like this and you all set to go.

Comment: @user2813740 Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `[string1 isEqualToString:string2]`

In that case it will evaluate to true only if strings are equal.

You may also use `containString` method. You may find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c) helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

`NSPredicate` is nice, another way is using `containsString:` method like

```
//assumes all objects in the array are NSStrings
- (NSArray *)array:(NSArray *)array containsSubstring:(NSString *)substring {
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *string in array) {
        if([string containsString:substring]) {
            [newArray addObject:string];
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

now you can call it like

```
NSArray *stringArray = @[@"P12300", @"P23400", @"P5430", @"P678"];
NSArray *subArray = [self array:stringArray containsSubstring:@"P23"];
NSLog(@"%@", subArray);
```

**Swift 3:**

in Swift it's super easy using [filter](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/)

```
let array: [String] = ["P12300", "P23400", "P5430", "P678"]
let newArray = array.filter {
    $0.contains("P123")
}
print(newArray)
```