# Compare two strings?

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

I want to compare 2 strings like if 1 string contain some part of other then it will true for example

```
if "test" == "es"
{
}
```

I want true in above case

**Note** - strings maybe of any length

Comment: u can use `"test".contains("es")` to check?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753956/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if "test".contains("es") {
    //...                
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `NSString` in Swift. Use `String` (which is also the default when you create Strings).

Anyway, `contains()` is what you're looking for.

```
if "test".contains("es") {
    // this will run
}
```

Comment: thank you friend...